# Dockerfile VOLUME does not mount host

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-machine

So I have a dockerfile with a `VOLUME` line, where I want to mount a directory from my host to my ubuntu container. The container builds fine, but then when it's run, the directory I want
to mount is empty.

I'm trying to mount this directly in the dockerfile, so I don't want to use `docker run -v`

How would I properly do this?

Comment: If you want to mount a directory you need to use a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/). You'll have to use a flag that does the same thing as `-v` like `--mount` as you can see in the documentation examples.

Comment: So there's really no way to specify a directory on the host to mount in a dockerfile? As in, you must run it with the `run` command?

Comment: Correct, you must specify a host dir when running the container. See [notes about specifying volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#notes-about-specifying-volumes). Your question might be a [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). What is your goal, what are you trying to accomplish by mounting a host dir in the Dockerfile?

Comment: I'm trying to mount the host directory using the dockerfile because I want to invoke the docker build command in python and then run a python script in the dockerfile and transfer contents out of the docker container. I have some dependencies (~60gigs or so) that would make it much easier if I could map the directories (host to container) directly rather than using copy

Comment: Could you use a `.dockerignore` file for that purpose? It may require specifying many paths but you can avoid copying large files and file path patterns that way. See docs here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file

Comment: I don't think that would work. I need those dependencies when running the python script. Specifically need them to build binaries.

Comment: Anyways thanks the help so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified in the [docs for the Dockerfile `VOLUME` instruction](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#notes-about-specifying-volumes):

> **The host directory is declared at container run-time:** The host directory (the mountpoint) is, by its nature, host-dependent. This is to preserve image portability, since a given host directory can’t be guaranteed to be available on all hosts. For this reason, you can’t mount a host directory from within the Dockerfile. The VOLUME instruction does not support specifying a host-dir parameter. You must specify the mountpoint when you create or run the container.

So no, you are not able to specify a host directory in the Dockerfile. You will need to use a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) and either the `--mount` or `--volume` flag as shown in the bind mount documentation.

If you're trying to avoid copying extra data in the build context, consider using a [`.dockerignore`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file) file.